# How to use a dictionary with python requests. - Outdated book. wunderground weather api

Tags: python

I purchase the make projects book for the raspberry pi and one of the scripts is using wundergrund api and then printing the results of stuff such as temp ect.

The code has changed and I have tried tweaking the variables but always get an key error :/

Here is a [sample api](http://pastebin.com/NzQL0UXK)

In the book he provides the code in python but it is using the old api code..
See Pictures

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAPma.jpg

Comment: When I click those links, I get the message, "We’re sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable". Can you upload the images to Imgur instead?

Comment: Updated sorry. http://imgur.com/n4kpsxo,DtYoQhJ

Comment: Can you show your code and the error. That sample api is just the JSON document from wundergrnd I presume.

Comment: @Kevin http://imgur.com/n4kpsxo,DtYoQhJ does the link work?

Comment: Thanks, I am able to see the images now.

Comment: Just "print forecast['estimated']['temp_c']" thats the part where it errors and the error is  KeyError: 'estimated' @kevin

Comment: As you can see in your pastebin ``"estimated": {},`` ie estimated has no subkeys it's empty. Yet ``forecast['temp_c']`` seems available, try that.

Comment: That's not the first problem he's hitting though.  The "estimated" element is nested under "current_observation".

Comment: in the original script it says forecast is the top level parent of the data so I thought if I changed it to estimated it would work :/ what parent should I be using :? I have tried with current_observation and same key error

Comment: Nope, the "temp_c" element is also under "current_observation".

Comment: If you don't already have a tool you like, something like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is very helpful in these situations.

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text-forecast.py", line 11, in <module>
    print forecast['current_observation']['temp_c']
KeyError: 'current_observation'
"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uu6qK6Rg I couldn't see the indents I've loaded a pretty version.

Comment: What is the parent for the tempc on your pastebin I cant tell :/ I have tried "    print forecast['current_observation']['estimated']['temp_c']" but again key error. @sotapme

Comment: JeremyC you should include the source code in the question, and give proper attribution to where it came from. An image doesn't help future googlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the prettier json document.

```
import urllib2
import json
txt = urllib2.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uu6qK6Rg').read()
j  = json.loads(txt)

print j['current_observation']['temp_c']
```

Gives

```
19.1
```

**EDIT**

To understand what's the under a key do something like.

```
print json.dumps(j['current_observation'], sort_keys=True,  indent=4)
```

Then you can slowly walk down the tree until you work out what the full path is to the data you want.

Comment: Good answer. Can you tell me why mine didn't work?

Comment: As I said prev. ``estimated`` is an empty  dict it has no subkeys called ``temp_c``.